# How can we convert us number format into European number format and still be of number type in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to convert a US format number (decimal part seperated by DOT) into a European number format(Decimal part seperated by COMMA) in Oracle.

I am partially successful in doing that by using below query :

```
select 13.01 US_Format, TRIM(TO_CHAR(13.01, '999G999G990D00', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.')) European_Format
from dual
```

where 13.01 is in US format and I am converting it to European format by using to_char. After this I get the value as 13,01 (i.e decimal part is seperated by a comma instead of a dot) which a character value, rightly so.

But now my requirement is to convert this converted value as number, but keeping the same format (European). Is it even possible  ?

I was trying to use `CAST` function for that , but that doesn't seem to give the result.

Can you please help me regarding this.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're storing it as a number it won't have a format, just a value. Read out the value and apply the format you want when you display it.

Comment: How numeric data is stored probably is not, and should not, have anything to do with the locale involved.  Instead, if you want to _view_ your numeric data in a certain locale, just use an approach along the lines of your current select query.

Comment: What is the datatype of the "US format number"? Values are not stored with any preferred display format.